# How to format cell as number/currency using HTML in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, formatting

I am trying to paste a table from Excel to Outlook using an HTML body.

The Excel sheet has negative numbers as red however when transferred to Outlook, they are black.

The following is part of the 'convert to HTML code'. The mso number format isnt getting picked.

```vb
If rCell.Column = 1 Then
    strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
Else
    strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt;mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0\.00_ \;\[Red\]\-\#\,\#\#0\.00\'>" & rCell.Text & "</td>"
End If
```

The code for the function.

```vb
Public Function ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(rInput As Range) As String

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim strReturn As String

    strReturn = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none;width:650px'>"

    For Each rRow In rInput.Rows

        strReturn = strReturn & " <tr align='Left'; style='height:10.00pt'> "
        For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
   
            If rCell.row = 1 Then
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt; background-color: rgb(180, 198, 231)'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
            ElseIf rCell.row = 11 Then
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt; background-color: rgb(180, 198, 231)'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
            Else
                If rCell.Column = 1 Then
                    strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
                Else
                   strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt;mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0\.00_ \;\[Red\]\-\#\,\#\#0\.00\'>" & rCell.Text & "</td>"
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
        
        strReturn = strReturn & "</tr>"
    Next rRow

    strReturn = strReturn & "</font></table>"

    ConvertRangeToHTMLTable = strReturn
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function (modified from the Ron de Bruin similar function) to allow conditional formatting, etc., remain:

```
Private Function CopyRangeToHTML(ByVal n As Range)
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, temp As String
    Dim wbs As Workbook: Set wbs = n.Worksheet.Parent
    temp = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".htm"
    With wbs.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, Filename:=temp, Sheet:=n.Worksheet.Name, Source:=n.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(temp).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    CopyRangeToHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    Kill temp
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set wbs = Nothing
End Function
```

You can then use the above function via `HTMLBody`, such as:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & CopyRangeToHTML(tableRangeRef)
```